# How to let gcc compiler know where a certain file is

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to compile my C code but I need to tell the GCC compiler where two file are.

The two files are located here

```
/usr/local/ssl/include/
/usr/local/ssl/lib/
```

I want to add this to my `gcc -o file file.c` so that my program can work.

Comment: To provide a search path for include files use the `-I` option, to provide a search path for libraries to link in use the `-L` option

Comment: like -I<pathtoincludefile> and -L<pathtolibfile>

Comment: Try using `man gcc`

Comment: path to include directory,, try `gcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -o file file.c` .. I'm not super positive about the order which is why I'm not answering,, but those are the right options for adding a search directory for include files and a search directory for static linking at least.

Comment: it worked, I dont think the order matter, if you want you can put it in the answer to I can checkmark it

Comment: hmmm, order _does_ matter for linking (although perhaps not for search directories, not sure) .. just curious.. does it fully compile if you try `gcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include -o file file.c`. You're not explicitly linking in any libraries, maybe you don't need that.

Comment: that complies as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gcc, the `-I` option is used for adding a directory to the set of directories to search for header files, and the `-L` option is used for adding a directory to the set of directories to search for libraries.  Since you're not explicitly linking in any libraries, you shouldn't need the `-L` option in this case.

```
gcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include -o file file.c
```

If you were linking in libraries, something like the following format should work, assuming that `file.c` calls a function in `libmyLib.a`:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include -o file file.c -L/path/to/my/library -lmyLib
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) for more details regarding library linking order.